# Dell Bluetooth driver - Invalid DFU file format

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, dell-vostro

My client is trying to install a Dell Vostro 1510 Bluetooth driver but receives the following error:

Invalid DFU file format (Not compatible with device or loader)

Can someone please help?

Comment: Are you SURE it is the correct driver?  If so, specifically which driver is it.  I can use my premier account to verify if you can include his service tag :)

Comment: Just in case, I looked it up for you.  Seems they only offer the one Bluetooth option on this guy - http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/555/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=V91MY&FileId=2731098417

Make sure he is using that one and you should be good to go.  If he is using that one, Post the Hardware IDs from the Device Properties and I can help you look it up to see what else it might be.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. They tried http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/au/en/audhs1/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=V91MY&FileId=2731098417 which appears to be the same driver. I'll try to obtain the Hardware ID for you. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes it certainly does appear to be the same driver.  I'd say get me those Hardware IDs and let's see if we can look it up directly.  And again make sure all the chipset and MB drivers are in or I could easily see this driver failing due to a "dependancy"